# Can we identify planets, moons, and large asteroids in our solar system have a unique spectroscopy?

Tags: observational-astronomy, data-analysis

I'm looking to create a database of relatively consistent measurements for various cosmic bodies. Please inform if there's a way to gather reproducible signatures, with the same set of instruments to derive the same measurements within a given margin of error.

If also possible, please link to an academically-trusted data source.

Comment: Terms like "simple database" and "unique" and "reproducible" and "good data source"  all need to be defined, or better-yet, replaced. I think you question is both too broad and needs clarity, and right now theres no way to tell what a "right" answer would be. Is it possible to narrow this down and more clearly specify what it is you need? *Thanks!*

Comment: thanks for the feedback, i'll edit